# UISplitViewController, how to always use UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm developping an iOS app targeting iOS 8 devices and I use a UISplitViewController.

I want to use `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay` as the default presentation mode for the Primary view Controller instead of `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModeAllVisible`.
But then, when I run the app, the UISplitViewController is already in UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay.

What I'm looking for is when I open the app, I'm in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden`, but then, presenting the primary vc should be in `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay`.

I use the delegate method `- (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc`

like this : 
   `self.splitviewcontroller.preferedDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;`
At instantiation of the SplitVC;
and then

```
- (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
{
    if (svc.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay)
    {
        return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
    }
    else
    {
        return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
    }
}
```

But it makes the constraints inside my primary vc break (but not when i'm not overriding `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:`).

Does somebody has the solution to my problem :( ?
Thanks by advance.

EDIT :

I tried to override the Idiom UITrait of the SplitViewController to iPad, but it doesn't work either :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I succeeded to make it "work".

On rotation I'm forced to change the display mode to `UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden` to avoid bugs.

I overrided `willTransitionToTraitCollection` inside my SplitViewController :

```
- (void)willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    self.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
    [super willTransitionToTraitCollection:newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
}
```

and then I overrided `targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController` in my SplitViewController Delegate :

```
- (UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc
{
    if (svc.displayMode == UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden)
    {
        return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay;
    }
    return UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden;
}
```

So now I have a very cool looking Overlay :)

Comment: Great! Did you get rotation to work? I'm using your delegate for portrait on iPad and all visible in landscape. Transition from portrait overlay to landscape all visible leaves a grey frame with an empty master view controller and detail gets full size - so gets stuck on overlay. I'm asking you before I start a new own question.

Comment: Yeah it work perfectly.
I will check tomorrow if I have made some changes on the code and edit my answer if this is the case